# wp-activate.php causing white screen of death

Tags: multisite

I'm developing a site for a client that will be part of a multisite.  I've added a number of new users, but when those users try to confirm their accounts they get the dreaded "white screen of death" and their accounts aren't activated.

Can anyone help me figure out why this is happening?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[**note**: I solved the problem before asking this question and thought others would find my research/solution helpful, see [Can I answer my own question?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer)]

The site in question uses a custom theme and site-specific plugin (that registers custom post types, custom taxonomies, etc), both of which I've written.

It turns out that the `wp-activate.php` bootstrap results in **plugins not being loaded**...which came as quite a shock to me (and is not documented anywhere that I can find).

My theme's `header.php` calls one of the methods defined in the site-specific plugin.  Since plugins aren't loaded when `wp-activate.php` runs, that method isn't defined and PHP dies.  To make matters worse, the `wp-activate.php` bootstrap also disables PHP error messages (even when `WP_DEBUG` is set to true), hence, the white screen of death :-(

### Solution

To solve the problem, I hooked into [activate_header](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/activate_header/) (the first hook fired *after* the `wp-active.php` bootstrap) and loaded the site-specific plugin myself, as follows:

```
add_action ('activate_header', 'load_site_specific_plugin') ;

function
load_site_specific_plugin ()
{
    if (wp_installing ()) {
        require_once (WP_PLUGIN_DIR . 'path to site-specific plugin') ;
        }

    return ;
}
```

See the *Gory Deatils* section below for why I tested `wp_installing()` before calling `require_once()`.

### Alternate Solution

Another solution would be to add a `header-wp-activate.php` (that doesn't rely on any methods defined in the site-specific plugin) to my theme.  For my purposes, that didn't seem to be the right choice, but might be for others.

### Gory Details

I have no idea *why* it was decided that `wp-activate.php` should not load plugins.  But here's a description of the relevant parts of the `wp-activate.php` bootstrap, and why it results in plugins not being loaded and PHP error messages to not be displayed.

First, `wp-activate.php` begins with:

```
define( 'WP_INSTALLING', true );
```

Defining `WP_INSTALLING` as true has cascading effects throughout the `wp-activate.php` bootstrap.  Most importantly for the problem I was experiencing, is that [wp_get_active_and_valid_plugins()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_active_and_valid_plugins/) (which is called in `wp-settings.php` as part of the bootstrap) contains the following:

```
if ( empty( $active_plugins ) || wp_installing() )
    return array();
```

Hence, the bootstrap thinks the site doesn't use any plugins even tho `get_option('active_plugins')` returns a non-empty array.

To understand why no PHP errors were output when WP died while trying to load my theme's `header.php` (again, even tho I have `define ('WP_DEBUG', true) ;`), we have to look at the way [wp_debug_mode()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_debug_mode/) is written.  `wp_debug_mode()` is called before the call to `wp_get_active_and_valid_plugins()` during the `wp-activate.php` bootstrap and contains the following:

```
if ( defined( 'XMLRPC_REQUEST' ) || defined( 'REST_REQUEST' ) || ( defined( 'WP_INSTALLING' ) && WP_INSTALLING ) || wp_doing_ajax() ) {
    @ini_set( 'display_errors', 0 );
}
```

So, not only does the `wp-activate.php` bootstrap not load any plugins, it also causes PHP errors that result from that fact to not be displayed; hence, the white screen of death! Argh!!!

Can anyone explain to my *why* it was decided that the `wp-activate.php` bootstrap should act this way?

TL;DR: see [the comment](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2017/02/22/nextgen-bootstrap/#comment-32271) I left on a thread about the Nextgen Bootstrap/Load Feature Project on Make WordPress Core.